# If $S=\{1945, 1946, …, 2016, 2017\}$ and $A = \{a,b,c,d,e\} \subset S$ such that $5 | (a+b+c+d+e)$, calculate the number of possible $A$s.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations, problem-solving

If $S=\{1945, 1946, …, 2016, 2017\}$ and $A = \{a,b,c,d,e\} \subset S$ such that $5 | (a+b+c+d+e)$, calculate the number of possible $A$s.

---

**Attempt**

First, we can gather some data, to be specific: finding the minimum and maximum sum such that it is a multiple of 5. Notice that:

$$ 5 | (1945 + 1946 + 1947 + 1948 + 1949)$$

and also

$$ 5 | (2013 + 2014 + 2015 + 2016 + 2017)$$

So we have found two such sets: $\{1945,1946,1947,1948,1949\}$ with total sum of $9735$ and $\{2013,2014,2015,2016,2017\}$ with total sum of $10075$.

First it seems that it may be reasonable that the answer can be obtained by using the fact that the number of non-negative integer solutions to $u + v + w + x+ y = n$ is $\binom{n+4}{4}$.

Here is my idea: we can first try to calculate the number of integer solutions of

$$  a + b + c + d + e = 9740$$

but with constraints $1945 \le a, b, c, d, e$. 
We can transform the above as
$$ (a-1945) + (b-1945) + (c-1945) + (d-1945) + (e-1945) = 15 $$

But this will overcount, for example, set $A' = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, because it appears $5!$ times, and also $2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 5$ will be counted which makes no sense because the variables must all have distinct values.
 So it will be difficult if we choose this path.

Let us just see a solution of $ a + b + c + d + e = 9740$ as organization of $9740 \: *$s and $4 \: +$s (with a rule $1945 \le a < b < c < d$ to simplify our organization):

$$ \underbrace{**…*}_{1946} + \underbrace{**…*}_{1947} + \underbrace{**…*}_{1948} + \underbrace{**…*}_{1949} + \underbrace{**…*}_{1950}    $$

---

But after doing tedious attempts, I think the solution may be found manually and look for pattern, notice that we have to find the number of 5 combinations from $S$ such that the sum is $9735, 9740, 9745, …, 10075$.

We know the only possibility for $9735$ is $A' = \{1945,1946,1947,1948,1949\}$. Then for $9740$ we just need to "increase" by $5$ to our previous set: $\{1950,1946,1947,1948,1949\}$ will do,  but is this the only one? no. There are more:

$$\{1945,1946,1947,1948,1954\}$$
$$\{1945,1946,1947,1953,1949\}$$
$$\{1945,1946,1952,1948,1949\}$$
$$\{1945,1951,1947,1948,1949\}$$

those are by adding 5 to one of the elements in $\{1945,1946,1947,1948,1949\}$. But by adding 2 and 3 to two elements we get:

$$\{1945,1946,1947,1950,1952\}$$
$$\{1945,1946,1949,1948,1952\}$$
$$\{1945,1948,1952,1951,1949\}$$
$$ \vdots $$

Comment: I would go about it by splitting your set $S$ up based on their equivalence classes modulo $5$, so $\{1945, 1950, 1955,\dots\}, \{1946,1951,1956,\dots\}$ etc...  Then, look at the number of ways that you can add five equivalence classes to get an equivalence class of $0$.  You have $0+0+0+0+0, 0+0+0+1+4, 0+1+1+4+4, 0+1+2+3+4, 1+1+1+1+1,\dots$.  Each outcome of which can be counted, for example for $0+0+0+1+4$, pick which three elements from class zero are used, which one from class 1 and which from 4, giving $\binom{14}{3}\binom{14}{1}\binom{13}{1}$... This seems tedious but would work...

Comment: @JMoravitz maybe you mean $\binom{15}{3} \binom{15}{1} \binom{14}{1}$?

Comment: Quite probably., I might have made an off by one error.  You get the idea I was trying to get across though